# How to run Gradle from the command line on Mac bash

Tags: java, macos, bash, gradle

I have a very simple question. I am brand new to Mac and I am trying to get my Java project moved over to my new Mac. The project has a Gradlew file that I thought I could run from the command line to build and run on any machine. When I do gradlew from the command line (in the location of the gradlew file) it says gradlew not found. Am I missing something on how to run a command from a bash shell?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`./gradlew`

Your directory with gradlew is not included in the PATH, so you must specify path to the gradlew.  `.` means "current directory".

Comment: Also if you get "./gradlew: Permission denied" using Mac Terminal you need to run `chmod 755 gradlew` first.

Comment: gradlew can be found in the project's root folder. added this comment because i couldn't find out!

Comment: Just my two cents, for those that still couldn't get it work and had followed the steps provided by Alex, at your directory, open terminal and run "./gradlew" and not "gradlew".. Works for me

Answer (score 122):

Also, if you don't have the *gradlew* file in your current directory:

You can install gradle with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with the following command:

```
$ brew install gradle
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928106/install-gradle-on-mac-os-x). Then, you are not going to need to include it in your path (homebrew will take care of that) and you can just run (from any directory):

```
$ gradle test
```

Comment: Pardon my ingorance here, but the OP wanted `gradlew` not `gradle` --am I missing something about the relationship between the two?

Comment: gradlew is a generated gradle wrapper for a project. The wrapper makes the project self contained and independent of the OS installed Gradle version. The Gradle wrapper documentation is found here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: so if I need to use gradlew just type gradle and it's ok?

Comment: I would use `gradlew` if it exists on the current path since it's a version tailored to a project and a specific distribution. Use `gradle` if the `gradlew` file can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

try this cmd

> git:(branch): cd android

> android git:(branch)  ./gradlew gradle build --scan