# Install / upgrade gradle on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, build, gradle, build.gradle

How do I install/upgrade [gradle](https://gradle.org/) for Mac?

Answer (score 470, accepted):

As mentioned in [this tutorial](http://www.jayway.com/2013/05/12/getting-started-with-gradle/), it's as simple as:

To install

```
brew install gradle
```

To upgrade

```
brew upgrade gradle
```

(using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) of course)

Also see (finally) [updated docs](https://gradle.org/install/).

Comment: Note the official guide:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html
which is frankly quite complicated...

Comment: I received following error while installing gradle using brew -  Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky.  _Please report this bug:_ https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

Comment: Works like a charm on **OS X 10.11.5**

Comment: Works well on OSX 10.13 (17A405)

Comment: In case you don't have admin rights, follow [this tutorial](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/solution-for-homebrew-user-without-admin-privileges-in-urs-local/782), replacing `walkloud` with your user name

Comment: As mentioned by ThomasW bellow, if you like flexibility and simplicity, sdkman is the way to go

Comment: symlink: `/usr/local/bin/gradle`. original installed path: `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/6.7.1/bin/gradle`.

Comment: Another way to install a specific version of Gradle is by using SDK Man.
https://sdkman.io/install.  after that check this answer it solved my prob.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/63995156/8390144

Comment: If there is an older version of gradle already installed, remember to run `brew link --overwrite gradle`

Answer (score 32):

## *SDKMAN!*

Another alternative is to use [*SDKMAN!*](http://sdkman.io/), a clever collection of shell scripts for installing/uninstalling various kinds of software kits.

An advantage of sdkman over brew is that many versions of gradle are supported. (brew only supports the latest version and 2.14.)

To install sdkman execute:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Then follow the instructions. Go [here](http://sdkman.io/) for more installation information. Once sdkman is installed use the command:

```
sdk install gradle
```

Or to install a specific version:

```
sdk install gradle 2.2
```

Or use to use a specific installed version:

```
sdk use gradle 2.2
```

To see which versions are installed and available:

```
sdk list gradle
```

For more information go [here](http://sdkman.io/usage.html).

Answer (score 20):

And using ports:

```
port install gradle
```

[Ports](https://www.macports.org/) , tested on `El Capitan`

Answer (score 20):

I had downloaded it from http://gradle.org/gradle-download/. I use `Homebrew`, but I missed installing `gradle` using it.

To save some MBs by downloading it over again using Homebrew, I symlinked the `gradle` binary from the downloaded (and extracted) zip archive in the `/usr/local/bin/`. This is the same place where Homebrew symlinks all other binaries.

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
ln -s ~/Downloads/gradle-2.12/bin/gradle
```

Now check whether it works or not:

```
gradle -v
```

Answer (score 9):

## Two Method

- using homebrew **auto** install:

  - Steps:

    - `brew install gradle`
  - Pros and cons

    - Pros: easy
    - Cons: (probably) not latest version
- **manually** install (for **latest version**):

  - Pros and cons

    - Pros: use your expected any (or latest) version
    - Cons: need self to do it
  - Steps

    - download latest version binary ([gradle-6.0.1](https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip)) from [Gradle | Releases](https://gradle.org/releases/)
    - unzip it (`gradle-6.0.1-all.zip`) and added `gradle path` into environment variable `PATH`

      - normally is edit and add following config into your startup script( `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` etc.):

```sh
export GRADLE_HOME=/path_to_your_gradle/gradle-6.0.1
export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

---

## some other basic note

### Q: How to make `PATH` take effect immediately?

A: use `source`:

`source ~/.bashrc`

it will make/execute your `.bashrc`, so make `PATH` become your expected latest values, which include your added gradle path.

### Q: How to check `PATH` is really take effect/working now?

A: use `echo` to see your added path in indeed in your `PATH`

```sh
➜  ~ echo $PATH
xxx:/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/gradle/gradle-6.0.1/bin:xxx
```

you can see we added `/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/gradle/gradle-6.0.1/bin` into your `PATH`

### Q: How to verify `gradle` is installed correctly on my Mac ?

A: use `which` to make sure can find gradle

```sh
➜  ~ which gradle
/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/gradle/gradle-6.0.1/bin/gradle
```

AND to check and see gradle version

```sh
➜  ~ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-18 20:25:01 UTC
Revision:     fad121066a68c4701acd362daf4287a7c309a0f5

Kotlin:       1.3.50
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_112 (Oracle Corporation 25.112-b16)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

this means the (latest) gradle is correctly installed on your mac ^_^.

for more detail please refer my (Chinese) post [【已解决】mac中安装maven](http://www.crifan.com/mac_install_maven)